# How to add Lightning Quick Actions on Account List View?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, list-view, lightning-quickaction

I have a Quick Action on Account with a Lightning Component that creates a new opportunity.

But I am unable to add the Lightning Quick Action to Account List View.

Is there anything to be added inside the Lightning Component for it to be available on List Views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only Quick action which are available for List view are of type:-

> 1. Create a Record
> 2. Update a Record

If you have any quick action embed with Lightning Component, It will not be available for List view.

As a Workaround, You can create List button with the help of Visualforce Page. It will be available for List view.

You will be interested in this:-
[Set Up a Mass Quick Action](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cases_set_up_lex_mqa.htm&type=5)